# Получение данных по URL

Tags: node.js

Только начинаю работать с NodeJS. Пишу скрипт и мне надо в нем получить данные с определенного сайта у которого есть API.

Примерно так http://example.com/api.php

Оно отдает ответ в формате JSON

То есть мне нужно при помощи GET-запроса получить JSON по ссылке, чтобы в дальнейшем работать с ним в моем скрипте.

http://example.com/api.php?param=1&param=2

Подскажите, как это делается?

Comment: Добавте пожалуйста ваш код прямо в вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Это называется обращение к API по "конечным точкам" (endpoints). На сервере API вы создаете интерфейс, который в зависимости от конечной точки будет выполнять определенные методы. Например, вот так это реализовано в VK:

https://vk.com/dev/methods

Далее при обращении к методу в параметрах GET/POST запроса вам надо указывать какие именно данные требуется получить (например, поиск по id и т.д.).

После получения данных с API парсите JSON-ответ у себя в NODE.JS:

```
var data = JSON.parse(response);
```